# Angular and NodeJs: Is passing id (generated in mongodb database) in the URL a wrong way of keeping track of users

Tags: angularjs, node.js, mongodb

I am using MEAN stack.Normally to collect data of a particular user I normally pass ID generated in mongodb database through **`$location.path`** in angular controllers, so the url contains the id's of my users .
But I don't know whether this is a secured way of doing things.
So can someone help me out what should be my approach.

```
`
```

Comment: to access this ID user need to be logged in to application?

Comment: This is not a good way. You should save the use on a session and use it to access user-specific data on the server and only send back data that the user can see.
Although exposing a generated ID from the database seems harmless, it's bad practice.

Comment: I am maintaing a session but session contains the admins details so how should I keep track of my users while moving to different pages.

Comment: Actually my question is If I get data of 200 users from db and if I clicked the 150th user how should i get his details. Currently i was doing it by passing id in the Url.

Answer (score 2):

Considering your last comment, when talking about an administrator reviewing a user's details for instance, yes it is the way to do it, like any resource from your database.

You may have an url like https://mycompany.com/users/{user's id} for instance, just be careful about the access rights.